# How can I filter the lists within the lists by ids python?

Tags: python, list, filter

I am getting data like this. Deposits from lists in this data should not be in other lists. How can I filter this list like this. Incoming data does not always have a specific index, number of deposits or withdrawals.

```
fakeData = [
    {
    'withId': 1232131212312, 'withAmount': 500, 
    'deposits': [{'id': 12321312312, 'type': 'deposit', 'amount': 250, 'date': '15-05-22 - 17:00:00'}, {'id': 123213123112, 'type': 'deposit', 'amount': 500, 'date': '15-05-22 - 00:00:00'}]}, 
    {
    'withId': 12326571312312, 'withAmount': 130, 'deposits': [{'id': 12321312312, 'type': 'deposit', 'amount': 250, 'date': '15-05-22 - 17:00:00'}, {'id': 123213123112, 'type': 'deposit', 'amount': 500, 'date': '15-05-22 - 00:00:00'}]}, 
    {
    'withId': 12321356712312, 'withAmount': 120, 
    'deposits': [{'id': 123213123112, 'type': 'deposit', 'amount': 500, 'date': '15-05-22 - 00:00:00'}]
    }
]
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you don't want deposits with the same `withID` to appear in multiple `fakeData` objects?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data after the duplicate deposits have been removed? It might also help to remove some of the superfluous keys and change your ids to be one or two digits.

Comment: Yes that's right @InigoSelwood

Comment: For example, the `deposits` ids in the first index are the same as the others, so the other `deposits` should be empty. @Steve

Comment: I would make a `seen_deposit_ids` set (or list), loop through the entries of `fakeData`, then loop through the `deposits` and either add the deposit id to the set if it hasn't been seen before, or remove it if it has.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def filter_packet(packet: list):

    def filter_deposits(deposits: list, stack: list):

        # Remove already-seen deposit IDs
        result = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in stack, deposits))

        # Add the IDs to a stack
        stack.extend([deposit['id'] for deposit in result])
        return result

    stack = []
    filteredData = []
    for packet in fakeData:

        # Filter the deposits
        new_deposits = filter_deposits(packet['deposits'], stack)
        packet['deposits'] = new_deposits
        filteredData.append(packet)

    return filteredData
```